# /bin/sh: error importing function definition for `module'

Tags: shell-script, rhel, pgp

I have script right now but it always prompt this is error.

`stderr=/bin/sh: module: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for`module' `

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# pgp.sh
# Script to take PGP Command Line 6.5.8 (Freeware) output from PGPPackageService
# or PGPUnpackageService and execute the appropriate GnuPG commands 
#
if [ "$9" = "-se" ]
then MODE="encrypt_and_sign"
fi
if [ "$9" = "-e" ]
then MODE="encrypt_only"
fi
if [ "$8" = "-o" ]
then MODE="decrypt"
fi
#
case "$MODE" in
    "encrypt_and_sign")
        #
        # Logic for encrypt and sign
        #
        if [ "$6" = "+armor=on" ];
            then
                OPTIONS='--armor '$OPTIONS
        fi
        if [ "$7" = "+textmode=on" ];
            then
                OPTIONS='--textmode '$OPTIONS
        fi
        PASS=${15}
        OUTFILE=${17}
        USER=${13}
        REMOTE=${11}
        INFILE=${10}
        #Original script from Bryce
        #echo "$PASS" | "gpg $OPTIONS --no-tty --output $OUTFILE --passphrase-fd 0 -u $USER -r $REMOTE --sign --encrypt $INFILE"
        #script from Tyn, removed --passphrase-fd 0 and echo and double quotes
        #03252015: Tyn: Added --trust-model always for newly imported keys to be usable
        /usr/bin/gpg --trust-model always $OPTIONS --no-tty --output $OUTFILE -u $USER -r $REMOTE --sign --encrypt $INFILE

    ;;
    "encrypt_only")
        #
        # Logic for encrypt
        #
        if [ "$6" = "+armor=on" ];
            then
                OPTIONS='--armor '$OPTIONS
        fi
        if [ "$7" = "+textmode=on" ];
            then
                OPTIONS='--textmode '$OPTIONS
        fi
        OUTFILE=${13}
        REMOTE=${11}
        INFILE=${10}
        #original script from Bryce
        #echo "$PASS" | "gpg $OPTIONS --no-tty --output $OUTFILE --passphrase-fd 0 -r $REMOTE --encrypt $INFILE"
        #script from Tyn, removed --passphrase-fd 0 and echo and double quotes
        #03252015: Tyn: Added --trust-model always for newly imported keys to be usable
        /usr/bin/gpg --trust-model always $OPTIONS --no-tty --output $OUTFILE -r $REMOTE --encrypt $INFILE
    ;;
    "decrypt")
        #
        # Logic for decrypt
        #
        PASS=${7}
        OUTFILE=${9}
        INFILE=${5}
        #Original script from Bryce
        #echo "$PASS" | "gpg --no-tty --output $OUTFILE --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt $INFILE"
        #script from Tyn, removed --passphrase-fd 0 and echo and double quotes
        #03252015: Tyn: Added --trust-model always for newly imported keys to be usable
        /usr/bin/gpg --trust-model always --no-tty --output $OUTFILE --decrypt $INFILE
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like you have a broken exported function in the environment, as here (the function is missing a semicolon and the closing brace):

```
$ env "BASH_FUNC_foo%%"="() {  echo foo" bash -c "echo blah"
bash: foo: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: error importing function definition for `foo'
blah
```

Bash exports functions through the environment and automatically reads them from there, of course complaining if they have syntax errors. It does that even if started as `sh`. This would mean that you should get the same error when running any script, e.g. this simple one:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
```

You can check what you have in the environment with something like `env | grep module` (the prefix `BASH_FUNC_` and suffix `%%`, might not be the same). Then, you'll need to find out where that environment variable is set. It's rather hard to set one in a Bash script, though, since `%` isn't a valid character in shell variable names.